# Can i create Recipient View without clientUserId

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I need to create an embedded RecipientView from a envelope already sent on docusign.

**The envelope wasn't created using the API, so the signer (an aleatory customer) does not have the "clientUserId" field.**

So, if send the following request to docusign API:

```
$result = Docusign::createRecipientView('2d07f457-806d-4d3d-ad4f-14174b5d35ff', array(
         'userName' => 'Glaicon Peixer',
         'email' => 'gjpeixer@gmail.com',
         'AuthenticationMethod' => 'email',
         'returnUrl' => 'http://your-site.tdl/returningUrl'
      ));
```

the url returned does not allow the signature.

Is there a way to crate de recipient view URL for a customer (signer) that does not have the 'clientUserId' field? 
Or there is a way to add a signer with 'clientUserId' other than API (directly by te site of docusign)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - You cannot add a ClientUserId through the web console, and you cannot generate a Recipient View for someone else without a ClientUserId.

You *can* use the API to update the recipient to have a ClientUserId using the EnvelopeRecipients::Update method: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update